# Run-time error '13': Type mismatch in Macro

Tags: vba, excel, type-mismatch

I have recorded a macro to create a Pivot Chart. The Data Source is defined as a variable because the data keeps on changing. The macro ran well for a fewer number of rows (up till 20 no.). But as the data increases beyond the 20 no. of rows, the macro shows a

> Run-time error 13: Type mismatch.

The code is as below. The highlighted part shows error

```
Dim s As Worksheet, t As String
Dim i As Long, K As Long

K = Sheets.Count

For i = K To 1 Step -1
    t = Sheets(i).Name
    If t = "COMPARISON" Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Sheets(i).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
Next i

Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "COMPARISON"

Sheets("FRONT PAGE").Select
Nobid = Cells(11, 4)
Sheets("ARRANGED BIDS").Select
Finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

**ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Sheets("ARRANGED BIDS").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Finalrow, (7 + 2 * Nobid))), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15). _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="COMPARISON!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable1" _
    , DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15**



Sheets("COMPARISON").Select
Cells(1, 1).Select
ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = True
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("COMPARISON!$A$1:$C$18")
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").IncrementLeft 192
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").IncrementTop 15
With ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("Item No.")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
With ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("Item Description")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
End With
With ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("Quantity")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 3
End With
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-6
With ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("Item No.")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 3
End With
With ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("Quantity")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
```

Please, someone, help me resolve the error.
Thanks

Comment: What is `Nobid` ? and what's the value it has on that errored line? Use `Debug.print Nobid` before that line or simple `Msgbox Nobid`

Comment: Nobid is a number of bidders which is defined in the other sheet. I have checked the SourceData range, there is no problem with that.

Comment: Not the solution: But you should try to follow the [VBA Best Practices](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices).

Comment: @Raj are you sure Nobid is a valid number ? Because this Nobid = Cells(11, 4) while get value from the activesheet its better to specify from which worksheet you are getting the value

Comment: @newguy I tried that, but still, it shows the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below, it should take of you error, and all the `PivotTable` setting. Explanation are inside the code comments.

**Note**: I’ve removed all of the unqualified `Range` and `Cells`, and also the un-necessary `Select`, which slows the code down.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub copy_to_report()

Dim PvtTbl      As PivotTable
Dim PvtCache    As PivotCache
Dim PvtRng      As Range
Dim ws          As Worksheet
'Dim t           As String
Dim i           As Long
Dim FinalRow    As Long
Dim Nobid       As Long

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

' loop through all sheets, if one of them is name "COMPARISON" delete it
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name Like "COMPARISON" Then ws.Delete
Next ws
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Set ws = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
ws.Name = "COMPARISON"

' ***** THIS is the only variable I'm not sure what it's used for *****
Nobid = Sheets("FRONT PAGE").Cells(11, 4)

With Sheets("ARRANGED BIDS")
    ' find last row in column "A" in "ARRANGED BIDS" sheet
    FinalRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ' set the Range for the Pivot Cache
    Set PvtRng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(Finalrow, (7 + 2 * Nobid)))
End With

' Option 1: Set Pivot Cache
Set PvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, PvtRng)

' Option 2: Set Pivot Cache
'Set PvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PvtRng.Address(True, True, xlA1, True))    

' create a new Pivot Table in "COMPARISON" sheet
Set PvtTbl = ws.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PvtCache, TableDestination:=ws.Range("A1"), TableName:="PivotTable1")

End Sub
```

Comment: Just wondering: you have to delete the sheet `COMPARISON` before you can create a new sheet `COMPARISON`. Of course, otherwise you'd get an error as there can be only one sheet with that name in the workbook. But how about a pivot table with the name `PivotTable1`. Wouldn't you have to delete any prior existence of that table before you can create one by that name? As I said: I didn't check. Just wondering... Still, *(+1)* from my side (as always).

Comment: @Ralph there's no need to delete anything, you are right ! You can just update the `PivotCache` of "PivotTable1" with the updated dynamic `PvtRng`. However, in past posts, I worked my ass off to give a long and detailed answer, and I've found myself "losing" the check-mark to a bad answer (that also had `ActiveSheet` and `Select`). Now, with `PivotTable`s, I'm solving the issue raised, here it's `Set` the `PivotCache`

Comment: @Shai Rado Thanks, it worked. Just one thing, can you explain what was wrong with my code.

Comment: @Raj first your `(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Finalrow, (7 + 2 * Nobid)))` are not qualified with "ARRANGED BIDS" sheet. Second, I just prefer not to use this syntax to create a `PivotTable`, but rather split it to `Set PivotCache`, and later `Add` a `PivotTable` to a `Sheet`, and add the Pivot table's parameters inside the brackets (including the `PivotCache`), I found this method the easiest, and also I like to break down each section of the code to variables (it helps me use them later, and also debug it easily)

Answer (score 0):

Either you try this...

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Sheets("ARRANGED BIDS").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Finalrow, (7 + 2 * Nobid))), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15). _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="COMPARISON!A1", TableName:="PivotTable1"
```

Or try it like this...

```
Dim pc As PivotCache
Dim pt As PivotTable

Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Sheets("ARRANGED BIDS").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Finalrow, (7 + 2 * Nobid))), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)

Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:="COMPARISON!A1", TableName:="PivotTable1")
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create a pivot, here is what i use. Remove all the "xl." from code, i was creating them on new excel and saved them.

```
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set wb = xl.ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Data")
    Set rng1 = ws.Cells.Find("*", ws.[a1], xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
xl.Worksheets.Add
    xl.ActiveSheet.Name = "Pivot"
    xl.Worksheets("Pivot").Activate
        xl.ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
            "Data!R1C1:R" & CStr(rng1.Row) & "C" & CStr(rng1.Column), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
           TableDestination:="Pivot!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable3", DefaultVersion _
           :=xlPivotTableVersion15
xl.Sheets("Pivot").Select
xl.ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = True
With xl.ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("IC Status")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
With xl.ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("CompCode")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
End With
With xl.ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Aging from last action in PD")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
End With
With xl.ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("PD#")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 1
    .Function = xlCount
    .NumberFormat = "0"
    .Name = "Count of PD#"
End With
xl.ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").HasAutoFormat = False
Dim j As Variant
xl.ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("IC Status"). _
    EnableMultiplePageItems = True
With xl.ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("IC Status")
For j = 1 To .PivotItems.Count
DoEvents
.PivotItems(.PivotItems(j).Name).Visible = False
              With xl.ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("IC Status")
                  On Error Resume Next
                   .PivotItems("In progress AP Timisoara").Visible = True
              End With
Next j
End With
```